# Exception Handling with Boolean Expressions

Tags: python-2.7, exception

Is it possible to include a boolean expression like I've done below while exception handling using try/except?

For example:

```
while True:
try:
    grade = float(input('Please enter your your score:'))
    break
except ValueError:
    print('Please enter a numeric value, you dingus!')
except (grade > 1):
    print('Not a valid number, please re-enter:')
except NameError:
    print('Please enter a numeric value, you dingus!')
```

I'd like for string inputs to be handled by 'except NameError.' I'd like for numerics greater than 1 to be handled by printing 'Not a valid number, please re-enter:'

As is, the program handles strings and valid numeric inputs as intended. However, when I input numbers greater than 1, the program accepts my input and does nothing else. No except commands are executed and nothing is passed on to the function found below this exception handling piece of code. The program just stops and no error is given to help with debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
while True:
  try:  
    grade = float(input('Please enter your your score:'))
    if grade > 1:
      raise ValueError
  except ValueError:
      print('Not a valid number, please re-enter.')
  except NameError:
      print('Please enter a numeric value, you dingus!')
  except SyntaxError:
      print('Please enter something, anything!?')
```

Comment: Any input on how to handle blank input? For example, if someone just hits enter without entering anything?

Comment: Sure that'd be a SyntaxError according to my testing. Please see edited answer.